# python pandas.read_csv library print everything in one column

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have this python script:

```
dati = pd.read_csv(percorso_file,sep='\ s +', 
                   engine='python', header=0, usecols=[0])
print(dati)
```

the output is as follows:

```
220  T;2;Africa;24;Africa centro meridionale;983;Sa...
221  T;5;Oceania;50;Oceania;988;Terre australi e an...
222  T;4;America;42;America centro meridionale;992;...
223  T;4;America;42;America centro meridionale;994;...
224  T;5;Oceania;50;Oceania;997;Wallis e Futuna;Wal...

[225 rows x 1 columns]
```

It prints me all in one column, when in reality there are 20 of them, how do I get everything printed in multiple columns?

Comment: Change `sep= '\ s +'` to `sep= ';'`. The `sep` keyword argument is the column separator. In your file it's a semicolon, not whitespace.

Answer (score 0):

After importing pandas, as an alternative to using the context manager, set such options for displaying entire dataframes:

```
pd.set_option('display.max_columns', None)
pd.set_option('display.max_rows', None)
pd.set_option('display.max_colwidth', -1)
```